# Merging NSArrays to create new array with objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have 3 NSArrays, each one with 6 objects:

```
NSArray *A [Joe, John, Jay, Jason, Jonah, Jeremiah];
NSArray *B [Doe, Smith, Scott, Jackson, Johnson, Lewis];
NSArray *C [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

My model is:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@property NSString *number;

@end
```

I need to create a forth array where each  person object has a firstName, lastName, number.

```
NSArray *D = [0]Joe, Doe, 1
             [1]John, Smith, 2 
             [2]Jay.Scott,3  
             [3]Jason, Jackson, 4
             [4]Jonah, Johnson, 5
             [5]Jeremiah. Lewis, 6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of "merging arrays" you should create a custom class (let's call it `Person`) that has properties that hold firstName, lastName and number.

Comment: And if i want to create person objects by fetching the values  from the firstNameArray, lastNameArray and numberArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like following: (On a side note, please declare your class property with proper attributes)

```
NSArray *A = @[@"Joe", @"John", @"Jay", @"Jason", @"Jonah", @"Jeremiah"];
NSArray *B = @[@"Doe", @"Smith", @"Scott", @"Jackson", @"Johnson", @"Lewis"];
NSArray *C = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6];

NSMutableArray *D = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:A.count];

for (int i=0; i < A.count; i++)
{
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
    p.firstName = [A objectAtIndex:i];
    p.lastName = [B objectAtIndex:i];
    p.number = [C objectAtIndex:i];

    [D addObject:d];
}
```

Let me know, how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` for array :-

```
NSArray *A = @[@"Joe", @"John", @"Jay", @"Jason", @"Jonah", @"Jeremiah"];
NSArray *B = @[@"Doe", @"Smith", @"Scott", @"Jackson", @"Johnson", @"Lewis"];
NSArray *C = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6];

NSMutableArray *mutArr=[NSMutableArray array];
[A enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
 Person *p=[[Person alloc]init];
    p.firstName=A[idx];
    p.lastName=B[idx];
    p.number=C[idx];
    [mutArr addObject:p];
}];
NSLog(@"person=%@",mutArr);
```